# Regarding Google Playstore Automation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, appium, uiautomation

I have this project where I have to automate the Play Store using Java and Appium.

**Problem:**
The problem I am facing is, that it seems like the buttons in the Play Store are changing their id's dynamically. Let's say I run the program once, it works fine, but when I try for a second time it shows the element cannot be located.

I just want to press the install button and open button on the app page of the Google Play Store. I am facing this issue with just those buttons.

Code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(100));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc='Install']")));
            
            WebElement installButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc='Install']"));
            installButton.click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on Install Button");



            By openButtonLocator = By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc='Open']");

           WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(400));
            wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc='Open']")));
            
            WebElement openButton = driver.findElement(openButtonLocator);
            openButton.click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on Open Button");
```

Please suggest solutions to effectively identify the install button and the open button. Presently I am using the UIAutomator2 Plugin in Appium.

(Note: I ensured that buttons are visible on the screen. Though the buttons are visible respective to wait times, but it's still not working.)